# Plotting average in matplotlib from a line graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm fairly new to the coding realm and have been trying to familiarize myself with code for data analysis. I'm trying to figure out how to insert an average of the dataset in this line graph. It contains data from multiple subjects across multiple days, and I'm curious to know if there's any way that I can take an "average" of the data, or the lines, and insert that into this code so that it's displayed on the graph. I've tried searching stack overflow and the matplotlib.org but have fallen short. Any help on this would be appreciated!

**For further clarification: there are nine total subjects and each of them have an accuracy that ranges from ~50% - 100%. The data is compiled in an excel that has a row for "Days" (1-22) and "Subject" (with their corresponding accuracy on the given day, i.e., 50% on day 1, 65% day 2, etc).

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
Day = df['Day']
Accuracy = df[['Subject 1', 'Subject 2', 'Subject 3', 'Subject 4', 'Subject 5', 'Subject 6', 'Subject 7', 'Subject 8', 'Subject 9']]
plt.plot(Day, Accuracy, alpha = 0.3)
plt.axis([1, 22, 0.55, 1])
plt.axhline(y=0.8, color='black', linestyle='--', alpha=0.3)
plt.xlabel('Day')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.title("Days to Acquisition by Subject")
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xticks(Day)
plt.show()
```

And this is what I get: 
[Graph with results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVtvb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
Day = df['Day']
Accuracy = df[['Subject 1', 'Subject 2', 'Subject 3', 'Subject 4', 'Subject 5', 'Subject 6', 'Subject 7', 'Subject 8', 'Subject 9']]
Accuracy_mean = df[['Subject 1', 'Subject 2', 'Subject 3', 'Subject 4', 'Subject 5', 'Subject 6', 'Subject 7', 'Subject 8', 'Subject 9']].mean(axis=1)
plt.plot(Day, Accuracy, alpha = 0.3)
plt.plot(Day, Accuracy_mean)
plt.axis([1, 22, 0.55, 1])
plt.axhline(y=0.8, color='black', linestyle='--', alpha=0.3)
plt.xlabel('Day')
plt.ylabel('Average Accuracy')
plt.title("Days to Acquisition by Subject")
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xticks(Day)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Is there a way to insert that line in with the rest of them so that it's displayed with the rest of the data? I don't want the average line to replace the entirety, I would like the other lines to still show and have an average line running through all of them. Ideally with less opacity than the other lines. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, really appreciate it! Such an easy fix that I can't believe I overlooked.